# Using wildcard type in java generics

Tags: java

I want to pass object of `GameObject` class which would also implement `Collidable` interface. How should it look like?

```
private boolean isCollision(GameObject<? extends Collidable> collid) {
}
```

How should it look like? `collid` must be instance of both `GameObject` and `Collidable`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make sure that `collid` is a `GameObject` **and** a `Collidable`, you can use this syntax:

```
private <T extends GameObject & Collidable> boolean isCollision(T collid)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to define an interface that extends `GameObject` and `Collidable`. Then declare your parameter to be of that type.

```
public interface CollidableGameObject extends GameObject, Collidable {
}
```

Then your method might be:

```
private boolean isCollision(CollidableGameObject collid) {
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, generics don't appear to be needed. If `GameObject` is not already an interface, consider making it one?